# SQL Server - Average a column that sometimes has numbers and sometimes strings

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm working with a column that was poorly set up as nvarchar, it sometimes has a number, which I want to average, and sometimes letters, nulls, or an empty string value.  How can I get an average of all of the numeric values that are greater than 0 for this column?

Side question: If I want to fix the column, what's the best way to do it without losing any of the numeric values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not bullet proof but should work:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM your_tab
  WHERE ISNUMERIC(col) = 1
)
SELECT AVG(CAST(col AS DECIMAL(18,2))) AS average
FROM cte
WHERE CAST(col AS DECIMAL(18,2)) > 0;
```

---

SQL Server 2012+ has great [`TRY_CAST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql) function:

```
SELECT AVG(casted_col) AS average
FROM (
  SELECT TRY_CAST(col AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS casted  -- NULL if cannot cast
  FROM your_tab
) sub
WHERE casted_col > 0;
```

Comment: This is handy, I can use the CTE to fix the table, too.

Comment: Re: "Not bullet proof". For those new to [`IsNumeric()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql), it is notoriously [problematic](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/).